# Facebook popup being blocked on iOS Safari, HTML5 canvas button

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, html5-canvas, phaser-framework

I am using JS SDK for facebook login in my Phaser based HTML5 game. It works fine in android devices by opening a popup for logging in via facebook. But it does not work on safari/iOS device. I think the popup is getting blocked because its generated by tapping on a button inside the game and not cause of a traditional HTML button.

```
this.fbBtn = this.game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'sheet', 'Button-Facebook', this.loginGrp);

this.fbBtn.inputEnabled = true;
this.fbBtn.events.onInputDown.add(this.onFBLogin, this);


onFBLogin() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.status === "connected") {
            FB.api('/me?fields=name,email,first_name', function(response) {

            }
        }.bind(this), {scope: 'email'});
    }
}
```

Fb login opens up in a popup on Android, nothing happens on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

That issue got fixed already:

- https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/issues/4106
- http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/40114-popup-blocked-windowopen-in-pointerdown-handler/
- https://phaser.io/download/release/3.10.0

> The InputManager and InputPlugin have three new methods:
>   addUpCallback, addDownCallback and addMoveCallback. These methods
>   allow you to add callbacks to be invoked whenever native DOM mouse or
>   touch events are received. Callbacks passed to this method are invoked
>   immediately when the DOM event happens, within the scope of the DOM
>   event handler. Therefore, they are considered as 'native' from the
>   perspective of the browser. This means they can be used for tasks such
>   as opening new browser windows, or anything which explicitly requires
>   user input to activate.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I am using Phaser 2 CE and not 3

Comment: in that case, i believe there is a workaround by overlapping with an invisible html button/link. for a new game, i would highly recommend using phaser 3 instead though, but i assume it´s too late for that...

Comment: Yea, sadly it is too late for that. Okay, I will look for a workaround.